# Inbuilt message instead of my own in Try/Catch

Tags: c#

When I use a Try/Catch for open a file, the program display a inbuilt message instead of the one I have inside the Catch part, when I try to open a file that don't exist. Whats wrong and what have I missed?

```
 public void ReadFromFile(MainFrame obj, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
            var animals2 = (List<Animal>)b.Deserialize(filestream);

            foreach (Animal animal in animals2)
            {
                AddAnimalToList(animal);
                obj.UppdateListOfRegistredAnimals(animal.ID, animal.Name, animal.Age, animal.Gender);

            }
            obj.UpdateId(animals.Count());
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        finally
        {
            filestream.Close();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I discovered that the reason for the inbuilt message is somewhere before the code above! Something must be wrong in the code below that handles an event from the openFileDialog, because despite several messageboxes, non is displayed! What have I done wrong!? Help is preciated!

```
private void menuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TEST", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                motelManager.ReadFromFile(this, file); // Smart lösning!!

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error message", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: File not found message]

Comment: Are you aware there is an easier way to debug your program than adding message boxes? You can add breakpoints and/or step through your code using the debugger.

Comment: Is that the message you are talkin about ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know the debugger, but sometimes it feel simple to just add a messagebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if(!File.Exists(filePath))
   MessageBox.Show("Not found", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

for more info 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

```
private void menuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = false;

        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.


        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            MessageBox.Show("TEST", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TEST", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                motelManager.ReadFromFile(this, file); // Smart lösning!!

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error message", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }
```

if you dont want the default message for file not found use

```
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = false;
```

Comment: This is simple and good, but what if a user is trying to open a .exe file?

Comment: for that you check the extension Path.GetExtension for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx

Comment: Or what if the user has permission to list the directory but not read the file?  Or what if the file is damaged (file on scratched CD for example... happened to me just last night trying to install the original Starcraft :-)

Comment: For all other unknown exceptions the try catch block is used

Comment: i have moved the line string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
 after the user has clicked ok, cause if the user cancels it could give a null exception

Comment: I still get an inbuilt message saying the file could not be found when I'm trying to select a file that don't exist and none of my messagebox are displayed!? I don't want to give up! What could be wrong?

Comment: How can you select a file that does not exists, do you type in your own filename in the dialog box ?

Comment: Perhaps this type of message is unavoidable?

Comment: Yes thats the default message

Comment: Hmm, Ok, but why bother do a check if a file exist, if there is an inbuilt message!?

Comment: So that now gives you your answer

Comment: you would check if a file does not exist if your not using a file dialog box

Comment: If you switched it off, you can supply your own friendly message

Comment: openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false; didn't work! I still get the inbuilt messages and none of mine is displayed! But I guess I have to live with this!?

Comment: Only if you want to do the checking your self and give your own friendly error messages

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you try to close `filestream` in your `finally` block without checking whether it is non-null.  If

```
filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
```

fails,

```
finally
{
    filestream.Close();
}
```

is executed with filestream being null.

Try changing that to

```
finally
{
    if (filestream != null) filestream.Close();
}
```

or better yet, wrap your `filestream` in a `using` block.

```
using (filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    // Do stuff with your filestream
} // filestream.Dispose() automatically called, which in turn calls .Close()
```

Comment: Should the using be inside the Try part?

Comment: I still get the inbuilt message, despite the change inside the finally part

Comment: You still need the try/catch if you want to show your own message.  You could use @JohnnBlade's suggestion to pre-check the file's existence, but you still want the try/catch in case you can't open the file (e.g. you have permissions to list the directory but not open the file, or the file is damaged).

Comment: **Downvoter**: If there is something wrong with this answer, please share the problem so that we can all learn.